# set SUPER privilege(s) for mysql user in cpanel

Tags: cpanel

When trying to 
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
in cPanel
it says  #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation.
But i have already grand all privileges when created a user for the database.
There is also no section of Privileges in phpmyadmin.
Is there any way to directly add this permission from cpanel/phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do this on a shared hosting cPanel account, I am afraid that you won't be able to set these privileges, as they are not allowed for security reasons.

There has been a previous request to have this added [here](https://features.cpanel.net/topic/grant-event-mysql-privilege-for-user-schema):

But it is not included in that version, checking their [change log](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/11.44+Change+Log).

If, however you have root access to the server, you can turn this one in your MySQL configuration file:

> /etc/my.cnf

by adding the following line:

> event_scheduler = 1

You should then be able to grant event privileges via SSH:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-privileges.html